# Invoke REST endpoint in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, rest, request

I have an REST endpoint URL which needs to be invoked from ReactJs Homepage.

## ReactJS Code:

```
function Home() {
  return ( <div> Welcome to the Home Page!</div> );
}
```

## REST URL

http://:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/1_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: There are libraries which you can use to communicate with REST endpoints like axios, requests, needle etc. Just read their documentations and you will find a way :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke the API using `useEffect` and `fetch`

```
function Home() {
      useEffect(() => {
         fetch('http://:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/1_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`').then(res => res.json()).then(res => // do something with res)
       })
      return ( <div>
          Welcome to the Home Page!
        </div>
      );
    }
```